# Can you attack Time Eater as Classic Super Sonic?

Tags: sonic-generations

It seems that I can only get close to and attack Time Eater as Modern Super Sonic. No matter how long I spend boosting as Classic Super Sonic, I can never seem to catch up with Time Eater. I can dodge all of the boss's counter-attacks, but that doesn't get Classic Super Sonic any closer for a hit.

Sonic's friends tell me that I can switch between the two Sonics in my pursuit, but while I'm playing as classic, they say to switch to modern *in order to go after Eggman to attack*.

Is attacking the boss only possible with Modern Super Sonic, and not Classic Super Sonic? Or is it possible to get close enough for a hit with either one?

> The final blow does not count, as you have to combine the powers of *both Sonics* to blast through the fireball attack.

**Research**

- [This guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/627223-sonic-generations/faqs/63297) suggests that it's possible, "but it's extremely difficult." Not *remarkably* helpful, but still gets me thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as you have said.  It is *possible* to harm him as Classic Sonic, but after an hour trying myself, I found it rather difficult and as soon as I thought I was close enough, I'd have to switch back to 3D space.  A good strategy I found while fighting this guy is to just hold the boost button in 3D space, then when he switches to 2D space, try to collect as many rings as possible as, to me, it is easier doing it in 2D space.

That said, this video shows Time Eater being defeated as 2D only, showing that it is indeed possible:

Comment: All is right with the world :) And that video is marvelous.